# Youtube link iframe embed not working but iframe vlink works

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, youtube

When i use https://www.youtube.com/v/rd1KVr9JGQc%26list=HL1395917567%26feature=mh_lolz link for youtube, it is working.

But when i use 
https://www.youtube.com/embed/rd1KVr9JGQc%26list=HL1395917567%26feature=mh_lolz
It gives me an error.

I'm using

```
 <iframe width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/rd1KVr9JGQc&amp;list=HL1395917567&amp;feature=mh_lolz"></iframe>
```

for mobile website but it is not working and it is giving me youtube error.

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: The second link is simply a broken link or undefined in youtube.

Comment: in mobile i use <iframe width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/rd1KVr9JGQc&amp;list=HL1395917567&amp;feature=mh_lolz"></iframe> not working but if i use this link only change /embed/ to /v/ it work ..... but in mobile site /v/ not work